# Orphaned case error

Tags: java

I keep getting the error "orphaned case" on this segment of code. I looked up the reasons that it be spitting that error, but as for as I can see there isn't anything there. I tried redoing the segment completely, but still the same error came up. Can anyone help me with this error?

Code Segment

```
case '<': 
                         if(flag2 == false || stack.size() == 2)
                         {
                            if(flag2 == false)
                               a = 1;
                            temp = stack.removeLast();
                            temp2 = stack.removeLast();


                            for(int iii = 0; iii < el.size(); iii++)
                            {
                               if(el.get(iii) == temp)
                               {
                                  for(int jii = 0; jii < el.size(); jii++)
                                  {
                                     if(el.get(jii) == temp2)
                                     {
                                        for(int kii = 0; kii < mop; kii++)
                                        {
                                           if((lamp[kii][iii] == 1 && lamp[kii][jii] == 1) || (lamp[kii][iii] == 0 && lamp[kii][jii] == 0))
                                              bam[kii][test2+a] = true;
                                           else
                                              bam[kii][test2+a] = false;
                                        }
                                     }
                                  }


                               }

                            }

                            test2 = test2+a;
                            flag2 = true;
                            a = 0;

                         }
                         else
                        {
                           if(stack.size() != 0)
                              temp = stack.removeLast();
                           else
                           {
                              a = -1;
                              temp = ' ';
                           }
                           //for(int poop = 0; poop < mop; poop++)
                              //System.out.println(las.get(poop));

                           if(stack.size() != 0)
                           for(int ikk = 0; ikk < el.size(); ikk++)
                           {
                              if(temp == el.get(ikk))
                              {
                                 for(int jkk = 0; jkk < mop; jkk++)
                                 {
                                    if(lamp[jkk][ikk] == 0)
                                       bam[jkk][test2 + 1 + a] = false;
                                    else
                                       bam[jkk][test2 + 1 + a] = true;
                                 }

                              }
                            //  System.out.println(flag2);

                           }

                           for(int ill = 0; ill < mop; ill++)
                              {
                                 if((!bam[ill][test2 + a] && !bam[ill][test2+1+a]) || (bam[ill][test2+1+a] && bam[ill][test2+a]))
                                    bam[ill][test2+2+a] = true;
                                 else
                                    bam[ill][test2+2+a] = false;
                              }

                              test2 = test2 + 2 + a;
                              a = 0;
                         }
                         break;
```

Comment: post the code that contains the entire switch closure.

Comment: Make sure that your `case` blocks are **inside** of a `switch` statement.

Comment: `if(flag2 == false)
      a = 1;`
do you want to do `a=1` only or do you want to add  `temp = stack.removeLast();
                            temp2 = stack.removeLast();` also. add `{}` if so.

Comment: this is UGLY and not formatted code that does not use any coding standards. Look how you use parantheses. Do yourself a favor - read this https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html and fix your code formatting. You will see that the problem will be gone.